# Now Unable to Communicate with Create2 and Getting repeated Bat: messages via the serial port

Tags: raspberry-pi, irobot-create

After hooking up my Raspberry Pi4 to the Create2 for the second time, I am now unable to communicate with the Create2. When I open minicom on the pi I see the following messages repeated on the screen. I tried resetting the Create 2 and got the messages again. Has anyone seen something like this?

````
================Pasted from minicom on the Pi4===========================================

Welcome to minicom 2.7.1

OPTIONS: I18n
Compiled on Dec 23 2019, 02:06:26.
Port /dev/ttyUSB0, 17:57:46

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys

key-wakeup
batt-rx-decode-error: 1 invalid-bit (0)
batt-rx-decode-error: 6 invalid-sync (20)
bat:   min 16648  sec 33  mV 16028  mA 16  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
    Flash CRC successful: 0x0 (0x0)
bat:   min 16648  sec 34  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16648  sec 35  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 65535  mAH 1902  state 14  mode 9
initial-lithium-battery-capacity: set to 2068 mAH
initial-lithium-battery-level: set to 1902 mAH
bat:   min 16648  sec 36  mV 16028  mA -16  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16648  sec 37  mV 16028  mA -8  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16648  sec 38  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16648  sec 39  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16648  sec 40  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16648  sec 40  mV 16056  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
key-wakeup
batt-rx-decode-error: 6 invalid-sync (2)
bat:   min 16649  sec 26  mV 16056  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 27  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 28  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 29  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 30  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 31  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 32  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 33  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 34  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 35  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 36  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 37  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 38  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 39  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 40  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 41  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 42  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 43  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 44  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 45  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 46  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 47  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 48  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 49  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 50  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 51  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 52  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 53  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 54  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 55  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 56  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 57  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 58  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16649  sec 59  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 0  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 1  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 2  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 3  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 4  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 5  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 6  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 7  mV 16056  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 8  mV 16056  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 9  mV 16056  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 10  mV 16056  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 11  mV 16056  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 12  mV 16056  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 13  mV 16056  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 14  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 15  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 16  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 17  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 18  mV 16056  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 19  mV 16056  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 20  mV 16056  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 21  mV 16056  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 22  mV 16056  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 23  mV 16056  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 24  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 25  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 26  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 27  mV 16028  mA 0  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 28  mV 16028  mA -56  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 29  mV 16028  mA -56  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 30  mV 16028  mA -56  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
bat:   min 16650  sec 30  mV 16028  mA -56  rx-byte 90  mAH 1902  state 18  mode 9
key-wakeup-wheel-drop
batt-rx-decode-error: 1 invalid-bit (0)
saving bbox vars
```
````

Answer (score 1):

These battery charging messages are normal when the battery is charging.

What happens when you take the robot off the charger? Have you tried putting the robot into safe mode (b'\x80\x83') before sending commands? Have you tried either of the scripts on the iRobot STEM [github repo](https://github.com/iRobotSTEM/CreatePython/)?

Please note that I'm an iRobot employee but the postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies or opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...So I have now more information. I did not have the inductors necessary hooked up to the motor power connectors so I think the internal circuits of the Create2 were reporting errors.

I have now connected the recommended inductors and the robot works and I can control it but ONLY if it is OFF the charger. That is a big problem since I wanted the robot to function autonomously and return to the charger to charge and then resume once the battery was fully charged. If it is on the charger I cannot communicate with it unless I press the CLEAN button and then I can only communicate for 30 secs or so before it goes back to sleep (??).  Has anyone run into the same issue? I am using the python pycreate2 library (which I have expanded).